# Store Image to Sql Server with Asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

How can I store image to AspNetUsers table which is default entity for registration?

I created Asp.net mvc 5 Web application and the default authentication is
Individual User Accounts.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is better to store the URL to the database and use the FTP to manage the files.

Here is a [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1976497.aspx?ASP%20Net%20MVC%205%20Upload%20Image%20Save%20to%20Database%20Create%20Thumbnail%20and%20Display%20in%20View).

There's a really good paper by Microsoft Research called To [Blob or Not To Blob](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525).

Their conclusion after a large number of performance tests and analysis is this:

if your pictures or document are typically below 256K in size, storing them in a database VARBINARY column is more efficient

if your pictures or document are typically over 1 MB in size, storing them in the filesystem is more efficient (and with SQL Server 2008's FILESTREAM attribute, they're still under transactional control and part of the database)

in between those two, it's a bit of a toss-up depending on your use

If you decide to put your pictures into a SQL Server table, I would strongly recommend using a separate table for storing those pictures - do not store the employee photo in the employee table - keep them in a separate table. That way, the Employee table can stay lean and mean and very efficient, assuming you don't always need to select the employee photo, too, as part of your queries.

For filegroups, check out [Files and Filegroup Architecture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179316.aspx) for an intro. Basically, you would either create your database with a separate filegroup for large data structures right from the beginning, or add an additional filegroup later. Let's call it "LARGE_DATA".

Now, whenever you have a new table to create which needs to store VARCHAR(MAX) or VARBINARY(MAX) columns, you can specify this file group for the large data:

Check out the MSDN intro on filegroups, and play around with it!

I would create a new table for just images and you can attach the image to a user, or a category, or a product, Etc...

Please see below.

```
CREATE TABLE UserImage
    (
         ImageID int IDENTITY(1,1),
         ImageName varChar(50),    <!-- Image Name
         ImageData varBinary(MAX)  <!-- Image
         ON Data       <!-- the basic "Data" filegroup for the regular data
         TEXTIMAGE_ON LARGE_DATA   <!-- the filegroup for large chunks of data
    );
```

Now create your model for the image:

```
public class UserImage : IdentityUser
    {
        public virtual MyUserImage MyUserImage { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyUserImage{

             public int ImageId {get; set; }        <!-- Link to user
             public string ImageName {get; set; }    <!-- Image Name
             public byte[] ImageData {get; set; }
    }
    public class MyDbContext : IdentityDbContext<UserImage>
    {
        public MyDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }
        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MyUserImage> MyUserImage { get; set; }
     }
```

Here is a good [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx) to extending Identity.